# Established but hidden TCP connection

Tags: tcp, container, netstat, podman

On computer 10.196.111.161, I can see the following established tcp connection:

```
[10.196.111.161]# netstat -natp | grep 7000
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 10.196.111.161:7000     10.196.111.180:41748    ESTABLISHED 19802/java
```

At the same time, there is nothing reported on computer 10.196.111.180.

```
[10.196.111.180]# netstat -nputw | grep 7000
(empty)
```

How can I explain this?

---

EDIT

The client on 10.196.111.180, which connects to server 10.196.111.161, runs in a container (podman on RHEL). Why netcat is not showing connections originating in the container? Should I report details on our config files?

Comment: Is it an exam question, or a real case which happen often? For the first: you can poweroff (hard power off) and restart. First computer has no idea on it. Or firewall may filter some FIN (so timeout on second machine, but the first one has no ideas), etc.

Comment: real case... I will try reboot, but I am trying to understand it first

Comment: I think https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9293 cover many "anomalies". Check also Figure 5